# how to stop the code when the code has executed a certain amount of times?

Tags: java, loops

Name: runSequence4
Input: Intake feed, int n
Output: none
Action: Takes in an intake object and calls the method give(). It first passes the number 1 into
give and then alternates between -1 and 1. It does this n number of times.

How do I stop the loop when the code executes it "N" times?

This is what i have so far

```
public void runSequence4(Intake feed, int n){
    for(int x = 1;  ????     ; x = (x * -1)){
        feed.give(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean in *stop code*? do you want to exit the loop? return from method? exit the program?

Comment: I want the loop to stop executing after it loops "n" times

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {... }`

Comment: Also, please try not post questions without, at least, a very minimum of your research, as the loop constructs are the basics of the basics in Java, and I'm sure, that you would have found tons of example, should you have attempted, at least, to search for the answer on your question.

Comment: I did try I couldn't find any that could specifically answer my question and my friends told me that this a good place to post questions about coding

Answer (score 1):

Just add a variable `i` to store the current iteration and test whether it has exceeded `n`

```java
public void runSequence4(Intake feed, int n){
    for(int x = 1, i = 0; i < n; x = (x * -1), i++){
        feed.give(x);
    }
}
```